# Get value from object in array: js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is what my array looks like:

```
const items = [
    { uuid: '123-1234-567', amountMoney: '20,02' },
    { uuid: '111-111-111', amountMoney: '44.04' }
]
```

And I have the uuid key in the variable:

```
const uuid = '111-111-111';
```

Now based on this uuid, I would like to extract the value from the amountMoney: `44.04`.

How do you write this in a nice way in js?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
items.find(item => item.uuid === uuid) // -> found object
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.find` to find the object if the property `uuid` of the object matches the value of the variable `uuid`. Before extracting the value for `amountMoney` check if the object was found.

Example,

```js
const items = [
    { uuid: '123-1234-567', amountMoney: '20,02' },
    { uuid: '111-111-111', amountMoney: '44.04' }
]

const uuid = '111-111-111';


const foundItem = items.find(item => item.uuid === uuid);

if (foundItem) {
 console.log(foundItem.amountMoney)
}
```